# Vue.js using same v-model in same div classname

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js

I'm trying to use the same `v-model` in the same `div` `classname`.
My problem is if I use the same `v-model`, even if I type in one input, all input value changes like my image.

[image]

This is my HTML code-

```
<div class="mainScreenSellProduct">
  <div class="mainScreenSellProductMain" v-for="items in coinShopItem" :key="items.id" v-if="coinVisible">
    <div class="mainScreenSellProductDesign">
      <img :src="items.url" alt="No Image"/>
      <div class="mainScreenSellProductDesignColumn">
        <span class="mainScreenSellProductDesignColumnText">{{items.name}}</span>
        <span class="mainScreenSellProductDesignColumnSubText">하이브 코인 - {{items.price.toLocaleString()}}개</span>
      </div>
      <form v-on:submit="onSubmitForm">
        <input type="number" v-model="itemCount" class="inputTag" placeholder="수량">
        <input type="submit" value="구매하기" class="inputSumbit">
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

This is my JS code-

```
onSubmitForm: function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  const itemCount = this.itemCount;
  this.text = `${message}`;
  console.log("inputValue" + message);
},
```

I tried using ref but it doesn't work. Is there a way to solve this problem?

Comment: Where do you define `itemCount`?

Answer (score 0):

This is very evident that if you use the identical `v-model` for each item in a loop then every item is eligible to alter that same `v-model` property.

**The proper way to implement this `v-model` loop concept is that each item should have its own `v-model` property (`itemCount` in your case) and when you submit the form, pass that respective item's `itemCount` in the submit method.**

Here is a demo of your use case where I pass only the current loop item's `itemCount` property in the submit method.

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data() {
    return {
      coinVisible: true,
      coinShopItem: [{
          id: 1,
          name: "Item 1",
          url: "https://picsum.photos/200/300",
          price: 123,
          itemCount: 10,
        },
        {
          id: 2,
          name: "Item 1",
          url: "https://picsum.photos/200/300",
          price: 123,
          itemCount: 20
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  methods: {
    onSubmitForm: function(e, payload) {
      e.preventDefault();
      console.log('Item Count- ', payload);
    },
  }
})
```

```css
#app {
  height: 500px;
}
img {
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
}
.content {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div class="mainScreenSellProduct" id="app">
  <div class="mainScreenSellProductMain" v-for="items in coinShopItem" :key="items.id" v-if="coinVisible">
    <div class="mainScreenSellProductDesign">
      <img :src="items.url" alt="No Image" class="content"/>
      <div class="mainScreenSellProductDesignColumn content">
        <span class="mainScreenSellProductDesignColumnText">{{items.name}}</span>
        <span class="mainScreenSellProductDesignColumnSubText">하이브 코인 - {{items.price.toLocaleString()}}개</span>
      </div>
      <form v-on:submit="onSubmitForm($event, items.itemCount)">
        <input type="number" v-model="items.itemCount" class="inputTag" placeholder="수량">
        <input type="submit" value="구매하기" class="inputSumbit">
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```